# Registration ID become "NotRegistered" for no reason

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**During April**, we've start receiving a lot of '**NotRegistered**' errors. According to the Google docs it should happen only if app was uninstalled or updated, but in our case token can "**expire**" in ~40 minutes even if absolutely nothing happen with device.

And what makes things even worth is that if, let's say **reg_id_1** "expired" and server returns '**NotRegistered**' error - we push client to register again, but GCM provides same token which is 'NotRegistered'. App update do not help. Only reinstall or user reset(android user) helps.

So the **question** is - does anyone encounter the same issue and/or has some solution ?

**P.S.** I wonder, can it be connected to the April ClientLogin shutdown and something gone wrong on Google servers ? https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/RK1pw9Cy4Sd

**UPD** See this for response from Google

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/vkj_ph7vqRQ/b_Kq283wXUQJ

Comment: just to make it sure, do you check the token from server side while sending push? i mean that is not invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual answer is https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-gcm/vkj_ph7vqRQ/b_Kq283wXUQJ

> This problem was triggered under a specific configuration (the
>   application being installed in multiple android profile on the same
>   device) and a specific combination of events. Only a very limited
>   number of registration-ids have been affected by this problem, and
>   calling gcm.register() again would restore the validity of the broken
>   registration-id.

Answer (score 2):

There may be several reasons why this error would be firing on the server

- App was uninstalled
- ID expires. Prior to that you get notifed on your server that you should reintitiate the registration.
- Users's change their google account and they send the new ID
- Update to your app causes a new ID, old one expires.

It's best to remove the dead ID's from your DB and stop sending messages there.

Comment: Thx for your response, but app was not uninstalled, user has no google account and app was not updated. And regarding ID expiration - when we reinitiate the registration - GCM gives the same token which is already expired.

Comment: what is your min API? users are required to have a google account on android versions lower than 4.0.4